# How exactly do you use mapState?

Tags: vue.js, browserify, babeljs, vuex

I'm trying to use mapState in Vuex as follows:

```
    mapState({
        locations: state => state.locations,
        types: state => state.models.types,
        models: state => state.models.models,
        vendors: state => state.models.vendors,
        statuses: state => state.statuses,
    })
```

I get an 'Unexpected Token' compile error, with Browserify pointing at the first fat arrow. If I try and use the spread operator:

```
...mapState({
```

The compile error happens at the `...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is an [object property spread](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/). Pretty much nothing supports it natively at the moment, and the es2015 babel preset doesn't include it.

1. Install it with `npm i -D babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread`
2. Add it to your .babelrc. It should look something like this:

   `{
     "presets": ["es2015"],
     "plugins": ["transform-object-rest-spread"]
   }`

Answer (score 0):

It seems you dont have [babel](https://babeljs.io/) installed. Babel is a transpiler for JavaScript which turns ES6 into code that runs in our browser today.

You will be needing [babelify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babelify) in your setup of Browserify. you can go through any [tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/setting-up-es6-project-using-babel-browserify/) on how to setup babel with browerify, there are many available.

Comment: I do, it's listed under 'dev dependencies' in package.json:   `"devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.0.0",
    "babelify": "^7.2.0",`

Comment: @daninthemix Are you using those in your Browserify config as well.

Comment: Not sure what that is. I have this in `.babelrc` : `{
  "presets": ["es2015"]
}` Regardless, I have fat arrows elsewhere in my code that have compiled just fine.